# MFC: How to Set initial value of CMFCEditBrowseCtrl object?

Tags: c++, mfc, msdn, filebrowse

I have MFC application for which I want to add one dialog to browse file location, using `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` object. But I have not been able to set initial path properly, e.g. "C:\Program Files\Path".
When tried it is showing chinese letters.
How can i do that? I have the code as follows :

```
m_pathCtrl.EnableFolderBrowseButton();
m_pathCtrl.SetWindowText(_T("C:\\Program Files\\Path"));
```

But it is showing something like this ->[image: encoding problem]

How to properly show the path in English? Please Guide.

Comment: Any warnings during build? Is your project configured in UNICODE mode?

Comment: "configured in UNICODE mode?" Can you please tell me how to verify that?

Comment: That information is present in the project properties. I can't specify exactly where because it depends on the version of Visual Studio you're using, but that should give you a starting point.

Comment: The character set is set to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set". Is there any work-around to keep it as it is?

Comment: So, Unicode is off. That means `_T()` should map to nothing and `SetWindowText()` should map to `SetWindowTextA()`. Despite that, it looks like the control operates in Unicode mode (thus the incorrectly rendered string). Is there a `#define SetWindowText SetWindowTextW` somewhere in your code? But even then, the compiler should emit a warning, and possibly even an error.

Comment: No, #define SetWindowText SetWindowTextW is not present.

I initially tried SetWindowTextA("C:\\Program Files\\Path"); with same result. Don't have a clue what is wrong here :/ ?

Comment: Me neither. Does `SetWindowTextW(L"C:\\Program Files\\Path")` give a different result?

Comment: No. same chinese texts

Comment: Note that, in my experience, `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` only works correctly in Unicode builds. There's no way around it except by changing your project to Unicode. The control is from Common Controls V6, which is Unicode only.

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises because you are using the ASCII character set, but the control expects Unicode. MS explains how to set up an `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` in a dialog when using ASCII here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfceditbrowsectrl-class?view=msvc-170. Use the dialog editor to insert an edit control in the dialog, then change its type from `CEdit` to `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` in the header file.

You can also see the proper characters in the window by using SetWindowTextW; e g, `inputFilesCtrl.SetWindowTextW(L"C:\SomeDirectory");`. The Chinese characters you are seeing are what happens when a 1-byte character set is interpreted as a 2-byte one.